# ssis 2008, Freeze Panes on Excel with title

Tags: ssis

Im using SSIS for SQL Server 2008.

I have a SSIS which takes data from an SQL Server database and exports it to excel files.

On the Control Flow I have a Data Flow. On the Data Flow I have an Ole DB Source and an Excel Destination. The Excel Destination uses an Excel Connection Manager. On the Excel Connection Manager, a path for an excel file is defined.

The excel file contains the column names.

I have put the column names as freeze panes on the excel file. In fact I have freezed the first 5 rows of the excel file(the column names are on the fourth row).

If I run the SSIS at this moment it runs fine.

Now, I have placed a title for the excel file on the second row of the excel file. 
But in the SSIS, if I right click on the Excel Destination and click on Edit, and then go to the Mappings tab, I cant see the column names on the destination columns as I could do. The only thing I see is the title and some cells(f1, f2).

What can I do so I can see my destination columns as before and still have the title on the excel file?

Edit: Excel Data:

```
Code    Code2   Code3   
AB         31     MQ    
AC         32     MR
```

Thanks...

Comment: Or maybe I could add the title on the excel file after the data has been put on the excel file?

Comment: Can you post your excel data

Comment: yes, i just edited my question

Comment: You can skip the 1st 4 rows and read the data from where the column name begins .Use the sheet name as `SheetName$A5:C5`

Comment: Where should I put this declaration?........Is it on the Excel Destination properties?..........I have modified the OpenRowSet property of the Excel Destination and put this: SheetName$A5:C5, but I got error: "Opening a rowset for failed. check that the object exists in the database"........What shall I do?

Comment: I have placed  a named range on the excel file and made the Excel Destination point to that range. So problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have placed a named range on the excel file and made the Excel Destination point to that range. So problem solved. Thanks!